# Links at bottom differing between each meta site

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the list of sites available by clicking the StackExchange drop down and noticed that it doesn't always seem to match what is available in the bottom bar.

So for example the scifi meta seems to have many more links than the stackoverflow one. Is there a reason for this or some way to customis what is displayed in the bottom bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launched SE sites only lists other launched sites. Beta SE sites only lists Beta sites. Since Sc-Fi is  still in beta, it only displays the list of other beta sites, where as this meta will show a list of all the launched sites.

Comment: Ahh, well that is simple then! Only just really realised how many stackexchan sites there are so just hoping to get better at understanding. Many thanks for the answer